# Holonomy 2-functor transformation by transition functions

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, principal-bundles

The holonomy 2-functor on a $\mathcal{G}$-principal 2-bundle associates a bigon:
$$\mathsf{hol}_i(\Sigma):\mathsf{hol}_i(\gamma)\Rightarrow \mathsf{hol}_i(\gamma')$$
in $\mathcal{G}$ to each bigon:
$$\Sigma:\gamma\Rightarrow \gamma'$$
in the path 2-groupoid $\mathcal{P}_2(U_i)$ of the patch $U_i$ of the cover.

On the other hand, there are transition functions $k_i$, $g_{ij}$ and $h_{ijk}$ from $U_i$, double and triple overlaps $U_{ij}$ and $U_{ijk}$ to the coherent 2-group of automorphisms $\mathcal{Aut}(\mathcal{G})$, such that:

$$k_{i}:U_{i}\to \mathsf{Mor}(\mathcal{Aut}(\mathcal{G}))$$
$$g_{ij}:U_{ij}\to \mathsf{Ob}(\mathcal{Aut}(\mathcal{G}))$$
$$h_{ijk}:U_{ijk}\to \mathsf{Mor}(\mathcal{Aut}(\mathcal{G}))$$

satisfying weak analogous of cocycle conditions of ordinary principal $G$-bundles.

**My question**

How do the two last transition functions extend (in category theory langage) to become pseudonatural isomorphisms:
$$g_{ij}:\mathsf{hol}_i\Rightarrow \mathsf{hol}_j$$
and modifications:
$$h_{ijk}:g_{ij}g_{jk}\Rrightarrow g_{ik}$$

**How I understand it**

When passing from a patch $U_i$ to a patch $U_j$ local trivialization autoequivalences of $\mathcal{G}$ are transformed by the action of $\mathcal{G}$ on itself. Being in the 2-group $\mathcal{G}$, the image of a bigon in $U_{ij}$ by either $\mathsf{hol}_i$ or $\mathsf{hol}_j$ is not the same, due to the action of $g_{ij}(x)$ for each $x\in U_{ij}$ on $\mathcal{G}$, thus the function $g_{ij}$ extends to a pseudonatural isomorphism between the two 2-functors $\mathsf{hol}_i$ and $\mathsf{hol}_j$. For the $h_{ijk}$ functions, they are "transformations" between the $g_{ij}$'s, so they naturally extend to modifications of the pseudonatural isomorphisms. If this is correct, how to formalize it in categorical theory langage?